# how to fetch documents within a fetched document in promise

Tags: node.js, collections, promise, response, resolve

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "ASANA": {
        "benefits": [
            "5b185c59e7179a074bebfb13"
        ],
        "steps": [
            "5b186f46e7179a074bec04f5",
            "5b186e1be7179a074bec0402"
        ],
        "_id": "5b11a58d3d62f90c1c717913",
        "asanaName": "Shavasana",
        "asanaDescription": "useful for body relaxation",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Here I have fetched one Asana and how to get benefits collection using that `id`. Below code is to fetch Asanas.

```
const fetchAllAsanasDao = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        asanas
            .find({})
            .then((asanasResult) => {
                asanas
                    .find({})
                resolve(asanasResult);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: What is this? Are you using mongoose? The structure looks like a document out of mongoose. If so then please show the relevant schema and wherever "benefits" are stored. You're also wrapping promises with promises for no reason. Please give more detail in the question at any rate because this is really unclear and if you are actually using mongoose and MongoDB it's inappropriately tagged as well.

Comment: I am using mongoose. and i got the solution.thank you

Answer (score 0):

const fetchAllAsanasDao = ({}, {}, query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        asanas
            .find({}, {}, query)
            .populate({ path: 'benefits', select: 'benefitsDescription', })
            .populate({ path: 'asanaResources', select: 'asanaResourcesPath' })
            .exec()
            .then((asanasResult) => {
                resolve(asanasResult);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}